# Change column values based on other dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that look like this

```
df1 == 
IDLocation  x-coord  y-coord
   1        -1.546    7.845
   2         3.256    1.965
   .
   .
   35        5.723    -2.724
```

```
df2 ==
 PIDLocation   DIDLocation
     14           5
      3           2
      7           26
```

I want to replace the columns PIDLocation, DIDLocation with Px-coord, Py-coord, Dx-coord, Dy-coord such that the two columns PIDLocation, DIDLocation are IDLocation and each IDLocation corresponds to an x-coord and y-coord in the first dataframe.

Comment: Could you share what your expected output looks like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the ID column as the index of `df1`, you can get the `coord` values by indexing. I changed the values in `df2` in the example below to avoid index errors that would result from not having the full dataset.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'IDLocation': [1, 2, 35],
                    'x-coord': [-1.546, 3.256, 5.723],
                    'y-coord': [7.845, 1.965, -2.724]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'PIDLocation': [35, 1, 2],
                    'DIDLocation': [2, 1, 35]})

df1.set_index('IDLocation', inplace=True)

df2['Px-coord'] = [df1['x-coord'].loc[i] for i in df2.PIDLocation]
df2['Py-coord'] = [df1['y-coord'].loc[i] for i in df2.PIDLocation]
df2['Dx-coord'] = [df1['x-coord'].loc[i] for i in df2.DIDLocation]
df2['Dy-coord'] = [df1['y-coord'].loc[i] for i in df2.DIDLocation]

del df2['PIDLocation']
del df2['DIDLocation']

print(df2)
```

```
   Px-coord  Py-coord  Dx-coord  Dy-coord
0     5.723    -2.724     3.256     1.965
1    -1.546     7.845    -1.546     7.845
2     3.256     1.965     5.723    -2.724
```